# Publish and distribute a Google Sheets with App Scripts so user gets private copy of sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, app-distribution

Usually addons are the way to distribute a Google Sheets script, but I do not know if that is a fit for my case:

- The user will manually fill out a list of their contacts / friends and answer custom questions about them. So they will, in some sense, definitely need their own copy.
- This should scale reasonably well. i.e. O(users) copies of invisible tabs in a sheet is not going to work.
- The user should be good to go from clicking a link with minimal work. i.e. a dialog saying "Please make your own copy of this sheet!" and forcing them to fork is not ideal (although I guess it could work.)

**Idea #1: manual fork**

Very much not ideal to make the user go through that workflow *and* hard to implement. i.e. the dialog to copy-and-fork will of course be present in the *copy* so additional logic will be needed to (somehow) de-wire that.

**Idea #2: bootstrap + copy**

The next idea I have is two apps: 1) an installer that needs access to their Google Drive and 2) the sheet it will copy into their Google Drive.

This is...  okay. But I don't like that the user has to authorize an unknown script to have arbitrary access to their Google Drive (!!). Even a more specific question like "add a file to your Drive" would get out of this bind.

The other problem is that **the user seeing the example sheet makes it clear what the heck is going on**. This should feel *as safe* as copying a sheet (and be that safe), not like the relative hassle of "installing an app," much less one needing sensitive data.

**Idea #3: Obscure addon**

I'm not sure if an addon that lives inside of a spreadsheet can be self-discoverable.

But, from there, I believe the addon would unpack the entire structure of the sheet from script. This is something I can handle, even though it seems kludgey still. And this may even require the user having a blank sheet ready first?

Initially I asked about [tracking forks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42312245/count-forks-similar-to-github-for-a-google-sheet-in-which-i-am-building-an-app). Now I am much more ambitious in that I am looking for an actual proper distribution mechanism that is *not* asking users to just manually fork everything.

Comment: I'm a novice at this stuff but could you have the user fill out a Google Form then from the response of the Form responses sheet have an onSubmit script to create a Google Sheet and share / transfer ownership to the user that completed the Form?